# How essential is the war against nature for Maoism?

Tags: marx, marxism, communism

> Under Mao, the traditional Chinese ideal of 'harmony between heaven
> and humans' [and Marx's  theory of “metabolic rift” in capitalism] was
> abrogated in favor of Mao's insistence that 'People Will Conquer
> Nature'

Is anyone writing about Maoism as an answer to the climate crisis?

Comment: i found [this easily](https://www.dissentmagazine.org/article/political-scenarios-for-climate-disaster/) so it's climate mao or twitter haha